# why can't a zip file be modified without re-zipping the entire file?

Tags: compression, zip

Modifying or altering a zip file essentially cannot be done on the same file. To be able to do that, the old file along with the new changes are put into a new zip file by re-zipping the entire content. I wanted to know why is this necessary? Why can't a zip file be modified without re-zipping the entire file again ?

Comment: The compression scheme used may itself change depending on the size/content of the new file.  Also, you'd need to know where to append new compressed material, and it might be easier to just unzip and start with the source.

Comment: Okay. So the compression scheme is not fixed for zip files ?

Comment: Well I expect it would be fixed, but here's the thing: Let's say new content comes in, and by using a different strategy to remove redundant information, we could get a smaller final ZIP file than the strategy used for the smaller version of the file.  Then I'd expect the program take advantage of that.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research, it seems this is not the case. Zip files in fact do allow you to add/remove files without re-compressing the whole archive. In the most commonly used zipping algorithm "DEFLATE", each file is first compressed by itself, and the results are then joined together. This means that some potential is lost in terms of finding patterns across multiple files, but it does allow for better flexibility, which matches the most common use case of zip files. So essentially when you add a new file, you just compress that single file by itself, and add that to the archive. This is in contrast to other other formats like `.tar.gz`, where all the files are first joined together (`.tar`), and then the result is gzipped together.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

Comment: Yes, that could be true theoretically, but as far as i've seen the codes that do this, a tmp file is created and the new files are added into this temp file which is later written to the place of the original file. Creating a temp file from the original itself is a overhead. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Creating a temp file does not mean that the rest of the archive is recompressed, it just means that the existing data is copied somewhere. Copying is cheap, and the reason it's probably done is in-place editing might be more expensive to perform in terms of time complexity

Answer (score 1):

The zip file format was designed to *permit* modifying entries (changing, deleting, adding) *without* having to recompress the other entries. So you have it all wrong. You just need to copy part or all of the zip file contents over in the same file or a different file, but you do not need to recompress the unchanged entries.